# Capybara + RSpec + rbenv + Gitlab Runner: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver, nokogiri, rbenv, gitlab-ci-runner

We use Gitlab CI (Runner) to test our Rails app, however, when we use RSpec + Capybara + :chrome_headless, it just show following Error Messages:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.3-p205), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 1
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:36354
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-07-27 05:01:00 DEBUG Selenium Executing Process ["/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", "--port=9515"]
2018-07-27 05:01:00 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in `specs_for'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  from /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
2018-07-27 05:01:00 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:00 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:01 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:01 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
.......
2018-07-27 05:01:19 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:19 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:19 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:01:20 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
F

Failures:

  1) User auth. Login when locale is :en user login & logout
     Failure/Error: visit "client/login?locale=en"

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
     # ./spec/features/user_auth_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 20.71 seconds (files took 5.77 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/user_auth_spec.rb:12 # User auth. Login when locale is :en user login & logout

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

However, I can run irb + Capybara + Selenium + chromedriver on the same server without error:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'capybara'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
irb(main):004:1*   options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
irb(main):005:1>   options.add_argument('--headless')
irb(main):006:1>   options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
irb(main):007:1>   options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
irb(main):008:1>   options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
irb(main):009:1>   options.add_argument('--window-size=1300,800')
irb(main):010:1>   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
irb(main):011:1> end
=> #<Proc:0x000055c907680210@(irb):3>
irb(main):012:0> session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome_headless)
=> #<Capybara::Session>
irb(main):013:0> session.visit('http://www.google.com')
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> session.fill_in('q', with: 'Capybara')
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/HTML/BODY/DIV/DIV[3]/FORM/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV/DIV/DIV[2]/DIV/INPUT[1]">
irb(main):015:0> session.click_button("I'm Feeling Lucky")
Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible button "I'm Feeling Lucky"
```

One more thing... When I try to manually run test on the same server, I got additional Error `Could not find nokogiri-1.8.4` (but GitLab CI `bundle install` is okay, no error about nokogiri):

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:45802
2018-07-27 05:46:49 DEBUG Selenium Executing Process ["/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", "--port=9515"]
2018-07-27 05:46:49 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
2018-07-27 05:46:50 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:46:50 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:46:50 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:46:50 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:46:51 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
2018-07-27 05:46:51 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
```

I also try to downgrade chromedriver to 2.39 , but still the same error.

Please help, I have googled a lot but no luck. Thanks.

By the way, I didn't use gem `chromedriver-helper`, and local test on my dev is fine without error.

**Update**:

After I change to Firefox, it still shows Error:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.3-p205), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 1
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:34093
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-07-27 09:09:47 DEBUG Selenium Executing Process ["/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/geckodriver", "--binary=/usr/bin/firefox", "--port=4444"]
2018-07-27 09:09:47 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 4444]
2018-07-27 09:09:47 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 4444]
1532682587782   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
1532682587787   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
2018-07-27 09:09:47 INFO Selenium Skipping handshake as we know it is W3C.
2018-07-27 09:09:47 INFO Selenium -> POST session
2018-07-27 09:09:47 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:4444/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"ignore","moz:firefoxOptions":{"args":["--headless","--window-size=1300,800"]}},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"moz:firefoxOptions":{"args":["--headless","--window-size=1300,800"]}}]}}
2018-07-27 09:09:47 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "User-Agent"=>"selenium/3.13.1 (ruby linux)", "Content-Length"=>"235"}
1532682587980   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "--window-size=1300,800" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.UXuoXoODlZKn"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1532682589509   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 42912
1532682589639   Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Frame script loaded
1532682589646   Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Frame script registered
2018-07-27 09:09:49 INFO Selenium <- {"value": {"sessionId":"8028cc40-8b67-410c-9102-9cae185a3d23","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"62.0","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":true,"moz:processID":13154,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.UXuoXoODlZKn","moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin":false,"moz:webdriverClick":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"linux","platformVersion":"4.4.0-1041-aws","rotatable":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000}}}}
2018-07-27 09:09:49 INFO Selenium Detected W3C dialect.
2018-07-27 09:09:49 INFO Selenium -> POST session/8028cc40-8b67-410c-9102-9cae185a3d23/url
2018-07-27 09:09:49 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/8028cc40-8b67-410c-9102-9cae185a3d23/url | {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:34093/client/login?locale=en"}
2018-07-27 09:09:49 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "User-Agent"=>"selenium/3.13.1 (ruby linux)", "Content-Length"=>"55"}
1532682589668   Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Received DOM event beforeunload for about:blank
2018-07-27 09:10:49 INFO Selenium -> DELETE session/8028cc40-8b67-410c-9102-9cae185a3d23/cookie
F

Failures:

  1) User auth. Login when locale is :en user login & logout
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: visit "client/login?locale=en"

          Net::ReadTimeout:
            Net::ReadTimeout
          # ./spec/features/user_auth_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: @io.to_io.wait_readable(@read_timeout) or raise Net::ReadTimeout

          Net::ReadTimeout:
            Net::ReadTimeout
          # /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill'
          # /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:154:in `readuntil'
          # /home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:164:in `readline'
```

Here is the environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- rbenv 1.1.1-28-gb943955
- ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
  `(/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/shims/ruby)`
- Bundler 1.16.3 `(/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/shims/bundle)`
- Rspec 3.7.0
- selenium-webdriver (3.13.1)
- capybara (2.15.4)
- chromedriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7)
  `(/usr/local/bin/chromedriver)`
- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.75 `(/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable)`
- nokogiri (1.8.2, 1.8.4) both tried.
- ENV['PATH'] when manually run test: `/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bin:/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin:/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/libexec:/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/gitlab-runner/bin:/home/gitlab-runner/.local/bin:/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/shims:/home/gitlab-runner/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin`

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_bot_rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'vcr'

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
I18n.locale = :en

ERROR = ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # Devise setting
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path: /spec\/api/

  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  VCR.configure do |c|
    c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join("spec", "vcr")
    c.hook_into :webmock
    c.configure_rspec_metadata!
    c.ignore_localhost = true
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

spec/support/capybara.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15

# define server port
# Capybara.server_port = 3333

# define browser go to where (with port)
# Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3333'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  ::Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1300,800')
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

# :selenium :selenium_chrome and :selenium_chrome_headless are also registered
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_headless
```

spec/features/user_auth_spec.rb :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "User auth.", js: true do
  let!(:company) { FactoryBot.create :my_com }
  let!(:user) { FactoryBot.create :login_user, company: company }

  before(:each) { COMPANY = company }
  before(:all) { VCR.turn_off! }
   after(:all) { VCR.turn_on! }

  feature "Login when locale is :en" do
    scenario "user login & logout" do
      visit "client/login?locale=en"

      within('.modal-info') do
        fill_in "log-in", with: "test001"
        fill_in "log-in-pwd", with: "12345678"
        click_on 'Login'
      end

      expect(page).to have_text "Signed in successfully."
      expect(page).to have_text "test001"

      visit "/"

      find('.logout-btn').click

      expect(page).to have_text "Signed out successfully."
      expect(page).not_to have_text "test001"
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile (partial) :

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', git: 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git', branch: 'rails-5'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
end
```

.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
......
bin/rails db:test:prepare
bundle exec rspec
......
```

Comment: Try running chromedriver from the shell and see what it says.

Comment: it looks like this: `Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.`